# Trying to build a reusable function to build dropdowns with JavaScript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make this function reusable without hardcoding the text and val fields I'm getting back from my controller.  I'm close, but I cant concatenate the text element.  Any ideas of how this could work, or a better way to do it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    buildDropdown('MarketSegmentID', '/Home/GetMarketSegments', 
                'this.MarketSegmentID', 'this.Segment' + '/' + 'this.SubSegment');
});

function buildDropdown(fieldName, controllerPath, ddValue, ddText) {
    var options = $("#" + fieldName);

    $.getJSON(controllerPath, function (items) {
        $.each(items, function() {
            options.append($("<option />").val(eval(ddValue)).text(eval(ddText)));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `.val(ddValue).text(ddText)` ? Why eval() ? EDIT : Ok i've seen why

Comment: @Oliboy50 - Because the value being passed in for that param is something like `this.BlahBlah` and the OP is obviously trying to revaluate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the first thing is to be careful using `eval` in javascript - you may not be susceptible to abuse here but its worth understanding why people often say [eval=evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)

The first one, setting the `.val` of the option is easy. Pass the parameter as just `'Segment'` and you can just use square bracket notation to read the property:

```
options.append($("<option />").val(this[ddValue])....
```

The second one is harder, you want to build a pattern made up of 2 properties on the incoming object, and I assume you want to make this as dynamic as possible. One  option is to pass a function which acts as a delegate - in fact I'd be tempted to do this for both properties (val and text). The final thing would look like this:

```
function buildDropdown(fieldName, controllerPath, ddValueFunc, ddTextFunc) {
    var options = $("#" + fieldName);

    $.getJSON(controllerPath, function (items) {
        $.each(items, function() {
            options.append($("<option />").val(ddValueFunc(this)).text(ddTextFunc(this)));
        });
    });
}
```

And you'd call it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    buildDropdown('MarketSegmentID', '/Home/GetMarketSegments', 
                  function(o) { return o.MarketSegmentID }, // this function build the val
                  function(o) { return o.Segment + '/' + o.SubSegment } // this function builds the text
                );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked without any adjustments.  I need to read up on the use of delegates.